# How to apply a blur to a view with a mask?

Tags: swiftui

I need to implement an onboarding like in the image below. I can't apply blur avoiding the icon. I know how to do it using UIViewRepresentable, but I want to reach the goal using SwiftUI 2.0(min iOS 14.0). Is there a way to create such a masked blur without UIViewRepresentable?

UPD. I have a view hierarchy. I need to blur it(a gaussian blur effect with radius 5) and cover it with a black tint with an opacity 0.3 and a mask with a hole. Everything is ok, but the blur modifier also applies an effect to an element from the hole. It must not be blurred(like "Flag" icon at the screenshot). I can't separate this element from the view hierarchy. This onboarding view modifier must be reusable across the app.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more it is not clear what you are trying

Comment: I want to make a blurred tint with a hole for an area that must not be blurred

Comment: Maybe, if you know how to do it using UIKit you could show a code example in UIKit so it's clear for us what you want to do and we can just translate it.

Comment: We do not have blurred tint! I don’t know what that is! But are you looking to a blurred view that an area of it lets call it a shape like circle not blurred? And can you show an example of issue first then an example of your goal!? I am trying to make your question clear

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing so.

Either use the blur just on the background:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Icon()
            Spacer()
        }.background(Image("cat").blur(radius: 2.5))
    }
}
```

Or, when having a entire view in the background you can use the `ZStack` and just blur the View you want to be blurred. Make sure that the View/ Element you don't want blurred is above. Like so:

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("cat").blur(radius: 2.5)
            VStack {
                Icon()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used both times a entire View for the Icon which is probably a little over engineered but it gives you the idea:

```
struct Icon: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Both giving you this as result:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: I was going to answer as you answered here, this must be the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to my problem. I used some code from other answers and wrote my OnboardingViewModifier. I used content from ViewModifier body function twice in a ZStack. The first one is an original view, the second one is blurred and masked. It gave me the needed result.

```
extension Path {
    var reversed: Path {
        let reversedCGPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
            .reversing()
            .cgPath
        return Path(reversedCGPath)
    }
}

struct ShapeWithHole: Shape {
    let hole: CGRect
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
        path.addPath(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius).path(in: hole).reversed)
        return path
    }
}

struct OnboardingViewModifier<DescriptionView>: ViewModifier where DescriptionView: View {
    let hole: CGRect
    let isPresented: Bool
    @ViewBuilder let descriptionOverlay: () -> DescriptionView

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .disabled(isPresented)
            .overlay(overlay(content))
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func overlay(_ content: Content) -> some View {
        if isPresented {
            ZStack {
                content
                    .blur(radius: 5)
                    .disabled(isPresented)
                Color.black.opacity(0.3)
                
                descriptionOverlay()
            }
            .compositingGroup()
            .mask(ShapeWithHole(hole: hole, cornerRadius: 25))
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)

        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onboardingWithHole<DescriptionView>(
        isPresented: Bool,
        hole: CGRect,
        @ViewBuilder descriptionOverlay: @escaping () -> DescriptionView) -> some View where DescriptionView: View {
            
            modifier(OnboardingViewModifier(hole: hole, isPresented: isPresented, descriptionOverlay: descriptionOverlay))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a way to over engineered solution. There is no need to provide a `ShapeWithHole` in order for the blur to not overlay the other view as it wont do it in the first way due to the order of the `ZStack`. The `ZStack`'s use is particularly for overlaying content with different content. Just define your first view with all the needed modifiers and overlay it with a different one which wont be affected by the others view modifiers. See first answer to this question.

Comment: It is not good answer! for no reason complicated the other answer is the way.

Comment: The other answer is not solving the problem. It is not reusable. I can't use those code to show onboarding with a masked blurred tint.